# Why does this JavaScript code fail to add style to text?

Tags: javascript

```
var css = ["font-family"];

var a = document.getElementById("t");

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a.style[css] = ["Arial"];
}

<div id="t">Hello World</div>
```

It doesn't add any font to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Felix's answer, your style assignment doesn't make sense. You want something like:

```
a.style.fontFamily = "Arial";
```

Comment: Actually, I mean to use an array for 'style' and to use an array to give the values to it. Like this:                                                                  var css = ["font-family"];
var a = document.getElementById("t");                                                   for (var i = 0; i < css.length; i++) {
a.style[css[i]] = ["Arial"][i];                                                               }

Answer (score 3):

Because the `for` loop is never run. `a.length` will give `undefined` as `a` is not an array but a DOM element. `i < undefined` will always evaluate to false.

And as [@Box9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405143/box9) mentioned, don't put `"font-family"` and `"Arial"` in arrays. Pass the strings directly:

```
var css = "font-family";
var a = document.getElementById("t");
a.style[css] = "Arial";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("t").style[css] = "Arial";
```

As you can also see in the function name, `Element` is singular, not plural.

Comment: Also, neither `"font-family"` nor `"Arial"` should be in brackets

Comment: Re: last update - you also need to use fontFamily since style is an object (see my answer for an equivalent)

Comment: @BobbyJack: Only if you use the "dot" notation. If you access the property via a string, it is fine (and you can access object properties this way).